# Not able to place Figure and table side by side

Tags: graphics

I want to place a figure and table side by side in a single column document using code written below. I am facing two problems:
1. Table is out of margin and I am not able to scale it down.
2. Figure and table are not aligned side by side
Kindly suggest modifications to the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    chains,% <--- new\frac{•}{•}
    decorations.markings,
    shadows, shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{% <--- modified
    decision/.style = {diamond,draw, fill=blue!50},
    line/.style = {draw, -stealth, thick},
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw,  text width=4 em, minimum height=10 mm,
        align=center}
}
\begin{document}
     \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',scale=0.5]
            \tikzstyle{cir1} = [draw,  circle, node distance=1.5cm,scale=1]
            \draw (-4,0) -- (4,0);
            \draw (0,-4) -- (0,4);
            \draw (-2,2) node[ cir1 , label=above:f] {};
            \draw (2,2) node[ cir1  , label=above:e] {};
            \draw (-2,-2) node[ cir1 ,label=above:c] {};
            \draw (2,-2) node[ cir1  , label=above:d] {};
            \draw ({2} ,0) node[cir1 , fill=black,label=above:b] {};
            \draw (-{2} ,0) node[cir1  , fill=black,label=above:a] {};
            \end{tikzpicture}
                \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                \hline 
                {\footnotesize Original Symbol} & {\footnotesize Mapped Symbol}&  {\footnotesize Mapped Symbol}\\
                & {\footnotesize (1D Mapping)}&{\footnotesize ( 2D Mapping)}\\ 
                \hline 
                a &  With same real part (c or f) & c or e  \\ 

                & With same imaginary part (f or e ) & d or f \\ 
                \hline 
            \end{tabular} 

        \end{minipage}
     \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that the tabular is too big for the minipage.  You also need \noindent and should remove the space between the first minipage and \hfill.  The outer minipage is unnecessary.  Finally, you are aligning the bottom of the picture to the center of tabular.  Note, the top and bottom of a minipage are actually the baselines for the first and last lines, but pictures and tabulars are really only one line long.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than minipages, you can use a single `tabularx` environment, with a nested `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx} %
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    chains,% <--- new\frac{•}{•}
    decorations.markings,
    shadows, shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{% <--- modified
    decision/.style = {diamond,draw, fill=blue!50},
    line/.style = {draw, -stealth, thick},
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=4 em, minimum height=10 mm,
        align=center}
}

\begin{document}

    \noindent
     \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\centering}Xc}
        \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',scale=0.5]
        \tikzstyle{cir1} = [draw, circle, node distance=1.5cm,scale=1]
        \draw (-4,0) -- (4,0);
        \draw (0,-4) -- (0,4);
        \draw (-2,2) node[ cir1 , label=above:f] {};
        \draw (2,2) node[ cir1 , label=above:e] {};
        \draw (-2,-2) node[ cir1 ,label=above:c] {};
        \draw (2,-2) node[ cir1 , label=above:d] {};
        \draw ({2} ,0) node[cir1 , fill=black,label=above:b] {};
        \draw (-{2} ,0) node[cir1 , fill=black,label=above:a] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}} &\footnotesize
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
              Original Symbol & Mapped Symbol & Mapped Symbol \\
            & (1D Mapping)& ( 2D Mapping)\\
            \hline
            a & \makecell[l]{With same real part \\(c or f)} & c or e \\[3ex]
            & \makecell[l]{With same imaginary\\ part (f or e) } & d or f \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a redesigned table, we can have a larger figure:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx} %
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    chains,% <--- new\frac{•}{•}
    decorations.markings,
    shadows, shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{% <--- modified
    decision/.style = {diamond,draw, fill=blue!50},
    line/.style = {draw, -stealth, thick},
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=4 em, minimum height=10 mm,
        align=center}
}

\begin{document}

    \noindent
     \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\centering}Xc}
        \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',scale=0.8]
        \tikzstyle{cir1} = [draw, circle, node distance=1.5cm,scale=1]
        \draw (-4,0) -- (4,0);
        \draw (0,-4) -- (0,4);
        \draw (-2,2) node[ cir1 , label=above:f] {};
        \draw (2,2) node[ cir1 , label=above:e] {};
        \draw (-2,-2) node[ cir1 ,label=above:c] {};
        \draw (2,-2) node[ cir1 , label=above:d] {};
        \draw ({2} ,0) node[cir1 , fill=black,label=above:b] {};
        \draw (-{2} ,0) node[cir1 , fill=black,label=above:a] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}} &\footnotesize\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
            \hline
              Original Symbol &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{a}\\
              \hline
            Mapped Symbol  & \makecell{With same\\ real part} & \makecell{With same\\ imaginary part }\\
            \hline
            (1D Mapping) & (c or f) & (f or e) \\
            (2D Mapping)  & c or e & d or  f\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1. How can I remove outer boundaries.\\ How can I reduce size of table like we scale down a figure.

Comment: Do you mean the lines I've added to show the margins?  Delete the `showframe` option of `geometry`. You can reduce the size of the table using `\scriptsize` instead of `\footnotesize`,  but it's getting   hard to read then. For the same reason, `adjustbox` is not recommended. Maybe redesign your table, swapping rows and columns would be  a better solution.

Comment: @Ehsa: Please take a look at the variant I've added.

Answer (score 1):

`tikzpicture`, `tabular` etc have no special posotioning rules, they are treated just like a big letter, they go side by side if placed next to each other. If placed with a pace in between they forma paragraph that may be on one or two lines depending.

So you can just remove all the minipage and then they fit on one line if small enough.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    chains,% <--- new\frac{•}{•}
    decorations.markings,
    shadows, shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{% <--- modified
    decision/.style = {diamond,draw, fill=blue!50},
    line/.style = {draw, -stealth, thick},
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw,  text width=4 em, minimum height=10 mm,
        align=center}
}
\begin{document}

            \begin{center}


            \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',scale=0.5,align=center]
            \tikzstyle{cir1} = [draw,  circle, node distance=1.5cm,scale=1]
            \draw (-4,0) -- (4,0);
            \draw (0,-4) -- (0,4);
            \draw (-2,2) node[ cir1 , label=above:f] {};
            \draw (2,2) node[ cir1  , label=above:e] {};
            \draw (-2,-2) node[ cir1 ,label=above:c] {};
            \draw (2,-2) node[ cir1  , label=above:d] {};
            \draw ({2} ,0) node[cir1 , fill=black,label=above:b] {};
            \draw (-{2} ,0) node[cir1  , fill=black,label=above:a] {};
            \end{tikzpicture}%
\footnotesize
            \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}|c|c|c|@{}}
                \hline 
            Original &  Mapped Symbol&   Mapped Symbol\\
            Symbol     &  (1D Mapping)& ( 2D Mapping\\ 
                \hline 
                a &  Same real part (c or f) & c or e  \\ 

                & Same imaginary part (f or e ) & d or f \\ 
                \hline 
            \end{tabular} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Ehsa it's best not to ask new questions in comments but you can wrap in a figure environment, or use the caption package and `\capitionof{figure}{....}` you may also want  to piut minipage back around each tik+caption and table+caption pair